# Problem in understanding branch of logarithm.

Tags: complex-analysis

I have faced some problem in solving this problem.
Find a branch of logarithm at the region $\mathbb C\setminus S$ , Where $$S\:=\{(1+i)t : t\geq0\}.$$

Comment: Whats have you tried? How much experience in complex variables do you have? Usually people here expect you to give enough background to help them give you some hints, if that is appropriate. (And if this is a homework problem, you should say so.)

Comment: Homework problem